# Pass Parameter to Angular Controller from Page

Tags: angularjs, parameters, controller, angular2-directives

I have a Web Page which has two controllers , First controller list the Ads 
with Each Ad has AId which is display using {{x.AId}} . To Get the Ad Details in Next Div How to Pass {{x.AId}} to another controller on same Page ?

```
    var app = angular.module("myModule", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

    //This Gets all the Classifieds
    app.controller("GetClassifiedDetails", function ($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            url: "assets/services/MasterWebService.asmx/GetAdsList",
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.ListClassifieds = response.data;
            $scope.TotalClassifieds = response.data.length;
        });

    });


    app.controller("GetAdsVisitedStats", function ($scope, $http) {


        $http({
            url: "assets/services/MasterWebService.asmx/spAdsVisitStatis",
            method: "GET",params: { AId }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.ListAdsVistedStats = response.data;
            $scope.TotalAdsVisited = response.data.length;
        });

    });
```

Comment: are you using router?

Comment: No ,Can u suggest what should i Do to pass parameter to controller from {{x,AId}}

Comment: Quickest workaround can be making use of `$rootScope` OR `$sessionStorage` but beware these have their own expiration period.